# Reject DTS-HD MA

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding, transcode

I have couple of video files containing both regular DTS as well as DTS-HD MA audio tracks. I want to get rid of the DTS-HD MA audio streams during transcoding, but have not figured out how to do so.
I have tried `-c:a:codec:DTS copy`, but this also copies over the DTS-HD tracks.
The streams are arranged something like this:

```
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit) (default)
Metadata:
  title           : Stereo
  BPS-eng         : 1714423
  DURATION-eng    : 01:26:25.973333333
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 486185
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1111369156
  SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.8 linux(x64-release)
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-12-03 16:23:57
  _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
Stream #0:2(deu): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  title           : Stereo
  BPS-eng         : 768000
  DURATION-eng    : 01:26:25.973333333
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 486185
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 497853440
  SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.8 linux(x64-release)
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-12-03 16:23:57
  _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
Stream #0:3(jpn): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit)
Metadata:
  title           : Stereo
  BPS-eng         : 1014690
  DURATION-eng    : 01:26:25.973333333
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 486185
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 657769964
  SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001101
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.8 linux(x64-release)
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-12-03 16:23:57
  _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
Stream #0:4(jpn): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  title           : Stereo
  BPS-eng         : 768000
  DURATION-eng    : 01:26:25.973333333
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 486185
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 497853440
  SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001101
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.8 linux(x64-release)
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-12-03 16:23:57
  _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
```

I have a bunch of files to process so I'd rather not figure out the mappings fore each file manually. How do I reject the DTS-HD streams / only select DTS? I've tried [How do I extract DTS core from a DTS-HD MA track using ffmpeg or alternative linux based tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/813933/) which does not filter the HD tracks out.

Answer (score 2):

If your regular DTS tracks have a fixed bitrate as shown below,

```
Metadata:
  title           : Stereo
  BPS-eng         : 768000
  DURATION-eng    : 01:26:25.973333333
```

you can use

```
ffmpeg -in.mkv -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:m:BPS-eng:768000 -map 0:s? out.mkv
```

Comment: Oh, that's some outside the box thinking... +1 for that. I actually don't know whether that's true for all my files. I'll try it but won't accept your answer for now as it's not really _the_ answer. Thanks! EDIT: I cant vote for your answer, yet :(

Comment: Hrm, any way to use the `m:<key>:<value>` syntax to compare against non-`TAG:` stream attributes like `profile`?  (as returned by `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format`)

Comment: Something like `-map -0:m:profile:'DTS-HD MA'`.  Except functional.